# R: split a list of value ranges (in text) into two lists

Tags: r

I have a column of temperature ranges (or single temperature if only one reading was recorded) like this:

`"117-118"
"117-118" 
"117-122" 
"122-128" 
"123" 
"118-124" 
"118-124" 
"118-124" 
"123-128" 
"91-101"
...`

In R, how can I split this column into two columns (i.e., low temperature and high temperature columns)?

Comment: You can check `?strsplit` or just use `read.table`

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip! I was able to move forward using something like this: `as.numeric(lapply(strsplit(temp,"-"), function(x) x[1]))`

Comment: you should post that as an answer and then accept it when you get enough rep.

Comment: What do you want in the second column if there's just one number? Note that read.table won't work unless you use `fill = TRUE`

Comment: @NickK I guess it will depend on the purpose.  For my case, since I may be more interested in getting the average value instead of the high/low values, if there is just one number, I plan to assign the number to both lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input <- c("117-118"
"117-118",
"117-122",
"122-128",
"123",
"118-124",
"118-124",
"118-124",
"123-128",
"91-101")
```

Using read.table with a custom separator:

```
newData <- read.table(text = input, sep = "-", fill = TRUE)
```

Note the blanks will be filled in with NA. If you want the mean, you could do:

```
means <- rowMeans(newData, na.rm = TRUE)
```

You could also use `strsplit` and `sapply` as you mention in your comment like this:

```
newData <- t(sapply(strsplit(input, "-"), function(x) as.numeric(c(x, x)[1:2])))
# If you want NAs as before, change from c(x, x) to c(x, NA)
```

Comment: Thanks NickK, your answer is exactly what I was looking for and it's more concise than the one I got.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for some useful tips given by @akrun and others, I found a way to get this work:

```
temp <- c("117-118", "117-118", "117-122", "122-128" ,"123", "118-124", "118-124", "118-124", "123-128", "91-101")
low <- as.numeric(lapply(strsplit(temp,"-"), function(x) x[1]))
high <- as.numeric(lapply(strsplit(temp,"-"), function(x) x[2]))
```

This gives results as:

```
> low
 [1] 117 117 117 122 123 118 118 118 123  91
> high
 [1] 118 118 122 128  NA 124 124 124 128 101
```

In the case of single value, assign that value to both lists can be done as follows (may not be the best way but it works):

```
high[is.na(high)] <- low[is.na(high)]
```

Which leads to this result:

```
> high
 [1] 118 118 122 128 123 124 124 124 128 101
```